# Draw points along the surface of a cube

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

So for an assignment I have to morph a cube into a sphere. All that's required is to have a bunch of points along the surface of a cube (don't need to be connected or actually be on a cube, but has to form a cube, though connections would make it easier to look at) and have them smoothly translate into a sphere shape.

The main problem is I never learned how to make points in XNA 4.0 and from what I've seen it's very different to what we did in OpenGL (we learned the old one in a previous class).

Would anyone be able to help me figure out making the cube shape I need? Each side would have 10x10 points with the points on the edge shared by the surfaces of that edge. The structure would need to be easy to copy or modify since I would need to have the start state, end state, and the intermediate state to translate the points between the two states.

If I left out anything that could be important let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should familiarise yourself with [the Primitives3D sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/primitives_3d). It illustrates all of the rendering APIs that you need.

Here is how I would approach this problem (you can look up these classes and methods on MSDN and it will hopefully help you flesh out the details):

1. Create an array of `Vector3[]` that represents an appropriately tessellated unit cube around (0,0)
2. Create a second array of `Vector3[]` and and use `Vector3.Normalize` to copy in the vertices from your first array. This will create a unit sphere with vertices that match up with the original cube.
3. Create an array of `VertexPositionColor[]`. Fill in the colour data however you like.
4. Use `Vector3.Lerp` to loop through the first two arrays, interpolating each element to set positions in the third array. This gives you a parameter you can animate - you will have to do this each frame (in `Update` is probably best).
5. Create an array of indices (`short[]`) that describes a triangle list of the tessellated cube (and, in turn, the sphere and animation between the two).
6. Set up a `BasicEffect` for rendering. This involves setting its `World`, `View` and `Projection` matrices and maybe turning on `VertexColorEnabled`. If you want lighting, see the sample for details (you'll need to use a vertex type with normals, and animate those normals correctly).
7. The way to render with an effect is: `foreach(EffectPass effectPass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes) { effectPass.Apply(); /* your stuff here */ }`
8. You could create a `DynamicVertexBuffer` and `IndexBuffer` and draw with those. But for something simple like this, `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` is much easier ([here is a recent answer with some details](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/49578/288), and [here's another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14796485/165500) with a complete example of `BasicEffect`).

Note that you should only create these objects at startup (`LoadContent` is a good place). During rendering you're simply using them.

If you have trouble with your 3D rendering, and you're drawing text or sprites, see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) for how to fix it.